# What is Best way to return Data in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a question that what is the best way to return data in webapi.
for eg we can have 2 scenarios.

> 1) GetProductsById in which we recive an id and return data for that Id.
>
> 2) GetProducts in which we return list of data

so for GetProductsById we can do :

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var product = getProducts().FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

and for getting list:

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var products = getproducts();
        if (products == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException()
        }
        return Ok(product);
    }
```

I want to know the best method to handle not found scenario in both cases.

Comment: The best method would be whatever the rest of your application already does when it gets in such a scenario. Your question is opinion based and off-topic

Answer (score 1):

In both cases I would return a Bad request with the error message.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id){ var products = getproducts(); if (products == null) { BadRequest("Item not found.") } return Ok(product); }
```

Comment: In this case should be `NotFound` exception instead  of `BadRequest`

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making a general object that would hold your own `code` ,`message` , and `response object` like this:

```
 [Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class ApiResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public int code;
    [DataMember]
    public string message;
    [DataMember]
    public dynamic result;
}
```

The result holds your actual result where code, and message are customized according to your data validations.